# How to insert text into table with input field

Tags: javascript

This is the html code

```
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="output"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

And javascript

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

  var input = document.getElementById("input").innerhtml;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = input;

});
```

This javascript does't work whats the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `jQuery`.  You can refactor your javascript to this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  var inputValue = $('#input').val();
  $('#output').text(inputValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery use this.

```
$('#output').html('your input text');
```

if you are using native javascript use this

```
document.getElementById("output").html('your input text');
```

Hope this helps.